# Why is my new aftermarket battery grip draining power from batteries?

Tags: battery, canon-60d, battery-grip

After reading many reviews I decided to purchase the Zeikos grip but B&H discontinued it so I decided to go with the new [**Vello**](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/754629-REG/Vello_BG_C6_BG_C6_Battery_Grip_for.html) grip instead.

I think I might have made a mistake.  The grip seems to drain power from my batteries VERY fast.  I had the grip on camera with fully charged batteries and they were completely dead in a matter of days just sitting in my bag.  I then charged the batteries (genuine Canon) to 100% and turned the camera off. I turned it on every hour or so and took a picture of the battery status menu.  In 4 hours the battery power has gone down to 88% with power off and without taking a single picture.

What is going on? Is this thing defective or is there some setting I am missing?

I removed the grip and performed a similar test and the battery power has not gone down at all in 4 hours. The battery normally lasts a very long time so I was quite surprised to loose all the juice in a few days.

Unless there is a setting I can tweak I will return this grip and get a genuine Canon.  Do people out there have any similar complaints about the Canon unit?

Comment: I have the same problem with mine, but I think it's the LCD on the back that causes problems. Why when it has it's own lil battery for that I don't know, but it still draws from the main :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't used it, but I know that battery drain with aftermarket grips is a common complaint on photography forums.  And people with genuine Canon and Nikon units always reply that they have no such issues.

I would say it's a defect with that particular unit.  You could try a 2nd Vello grip and you may find it works well. It shouldn't drain the batteries in a matter of days with everything switched off.

Comment: oh no. thanks. no more aftermarket anything for me.

Comment: Some aftermarket stuff is good, including (probably) camera grips. I think the quality control is an issue.  If you swap for another one, it may be fine.  B&H wouldn't stock it for long if they got nothing but returns.

Comment: I have a different 3rd party grip (can't remember the make), and I have a similar problem.  I take the batteries out when I'm not using the camera.  :-(

Comment: Thanks guys.  I will just return it and get the Canon. Besides, this grip stinks so bad of rubber and plastic I can smell my camera bag from across the room.